# Why MongoDB ObjectId.isValid('surveillance') returns true?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a helper method in my backend that runs through the DTO and replaces strings that are a valid ObjectId with an ObjectId instance:

```js
import { Types, isValidObjectId } from 'mongoose';

if (typeof input === 'string' && isValidObjectId(input)) 
    return new Types.ObjectId(input);
return input;
```

So I came upon a logical error and after I traced it, I realized the error came from the fact that `ObjectId.isValid('surveillance')` returns `true`!

Comment: Refer to this conversation in [github](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11209)

Comment: @turivishal I see, thanks, but I still don't understand why it returns true! it isn't a bug? so the method checks if a value "can convert" to ObjectId instead of is it a "valid" ObjectId?

Comment: It is resolved in the latest Mongoose version, you can update and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `new Types.ObjectId(...)` attempts to create a valid ObjectId from the provided input.

The usually expected input is a 24-character string of hex digits, but 12-byte binary buffers are also accepted.

If the passed input can be passed to `Buffer.from(...)` and result in a 12-byte buffer, it will be accepted as a valid ObjectId.

A quick demo from the node REPL, note that an ObjectId is actually created, and the hex of the ObjectId matches the byte generated by `Buffer.from`:

```
> const {Types, isValidObjectId } = await import( 'mongoose')
> id = new Types.ObjectId("surveillance")
new ObjectId("7375727665696c6c616e6365")
> Buffer.from("surveillance")
<Buffer 73 75 72 76 65 69 6c 6c 61 6e 63 65>
```

In theory, this means that any value that `Buffer.from()` can convert to a 12-byte buffer is a valid ObjectId.